# Transferring site's files

Tags: wordpress

I am a non developer and I have this task of making a replica of the wordpress website
I asked my manager to give me the neccessary permissions and now I can see the project
I don't know how to download the Wordpress site in my console, I don't know where are the wordpress files and I asked couple of developers without any result

I need to see the files so I would be able to update the wordpress version
And make a repilica on a subdomain for some one else

Can you help me please?

I tried so many different things but since I have no idea what I am doing I couldn't complete my steps

Answer (score 0):

You can download, with ftp, the wp-content folder and make a dump of the database. With these two you can clone a WordPress site.
You can also use plugin like all in one wp migration